# Запятая перед указанием объема/количества вещества

Tags: пунктуация

Всегда ли ставится запятая в таких случаях или можно без нее?

Лекарственная форма: раствор для инъекций, 30 мг/мл.

Лекарственная форма: раствор для инъекций 30 мг/мл.

Answer (score 1):

В Сети преобладают подобные конструкции без запятых. Я бы отнес это к профессиональному сленгу фармацевтов (из несогласованного определения "концентрацией 30 мг/мл" выбросили для краткости слово "концентрацией").

Если нельзя вернуть слово "концентрацией", а бы поставил скобки, все другие варианты могут только запутать читателя: запятая создает впечатление перечисления, тире наводит на мысль о количестве вещества.